# Migrate Facebook App group to Page

Tags: facebook, migrate

I had a warning in my App group that on 1st February the app groups were going to "close" and asking for migrating to a Page.

I created a Page with the same name as my app group and clicked on migrate. However, now when I access to my app group it says to go to the application so it hasn't been migrated.

My question is, have I lost all my fans? Do I have to start from the beginning again?

This is my app group: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=138907922791629
This is my new page: http://www.facebook.com/fmsite

What should I do to recover my 2700 members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the following from [this Facebook blog entry](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/):

> **The Like migration can take up to seven days, and it may be several hours before you see any movement on the Page.** If you have a Vanity URL associated with your App Profile Page, we will transfer the Vanity URL to the Facebook Page so long as one doesn’t already exist for the Page.
>
> If no action is taken before February 1st, 2012, your App Profile Page will be deleted and we will send all App Profile Page traffic directly to your app.

Comment: So, theoretically, the likes will be transfered to the new Page? Is there any way to see if Facebook has detected the new Page and they are working on it? Sorry, it seems that my new Page is totally independent. :S Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i don't know if there is a way to tell for sure, that facebook has started working on it. But if your old app page has been **deleted** then obviously it means that migration has started!! Because that's what they mention in the blog article i linked in the answer, if you haven't read it then please do. Further as long as your new page has the **same name** as your **app** , migration will happen, atleast that's what the blog article says.